# Why when I use Thread class in Console Application, my Application waits until it ends?

Tags: c#, multithreading

When I run method by using Thread class, It didn't close immediately, It waits until second thread finish and then close ConsoleApp.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting Main: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        Thread thread = new Thread(Circle);
        thread.Start();


        Console.WriteLine("Ending Main: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    }

    static void Circle()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Working on Background thread: {0}", i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

But, when I run same method with class Task, It close application immediately.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting Main: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);


        Task t = new Task(Circle);
        t.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Ending Main: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);


    }

    static void Circle()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Working on Background thread: {0}", i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Guys, thanks, I understand. My code in C#, I'm using Gist for demo codes, I thought it can understand and show my C# code. In Preview all was okay, but when I publish post, it breaks all. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a thread by default it is a foreground thread. An application waits for all foreground threads to exit [before the application exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx)

When you create a `Task` this is run on a thread from the thread pool, which are background threads, therefore the application can exit even if the `Task` has not completed.

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments, you should wait for a `Task` if you want the process not to exit until the `Task` finishes. You can also wait for background threads using `Join` so the behavior of a `Task` is similar to a background `Thread` with regard to process termination. You must explicitly wait for either of them or the process terminates.

Comment: Actually, the reason why the thread example exits immediately is because he does not `await` it.  It's an example of a _fire-and-forget_ task

Comment: @MickyD You are right that is one cause of it, and I will update the answer to reflect that (when I wrote the answer some of the code was not visible). But the primary reason why the task does not keep the process alive even though it is still running while the Thread does, is the one stated in my answer. You could in theory wait for the Thread as well using `Join`, and if it were a background thread the behavior would be the same, no join, process exists. The question was why this similar looking code behaves differently

Comment: Well no, `Join` blocks the calling thread.  `Join` does not equal `await`.  Tasks are not threads.  It is incorrect to compare them to threads.  It is not useful arguably to say they are background threads

Comment: Until recently you couldn't `await` in the entry point method, you would have had to do a `Wait` (or equivalent), which would have blocked the main thread as well. (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/). I agree Tasks are not Threads, but both can be used to run a pice of code in the background, and this is what the question was about, in this regard they are similar.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, thanks. Your answer is what I'm expected. I'm many years in c#, but sometimes some simple question burning in your mind. I know how to stop or wait for thread and also working with async/await, but I really didn't know about this difference. Thanks for answer.